# pseudo-class :last-child weirdness

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, css-selectors

I'd like the last menu item to be blue, and I'm trying to use the psuedo-class `a:last child` to accomplish this.  Weird thing is, it's applying the rule to a seemingly random `a:link` in the middle of the menu.  Can you tell me why?

site:
http://www.robert-wright-books.com/STAGE

CSS:

```
#access {
 background: transparent;
 float: left;
 font-size: 1.4em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 238px;
 margin: 36px 0 0 18px;
}
#access a:last-child {  color: #006ccf }
#access ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
#access ul li { border-bottom: 1px dotted #957e5e }
#access ul li:last-child { border-bottom: none }
#access ul li a,
#access ul li a:hover,
#access ul li a:visited {
 color: #432f00;
 display: block;
 padding: 6px 24px;
 line-height: 17px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any randomly blue element. What browser are you using?

Comment: I assume you are testing in IE or something else because it's fine in firefox.

Comment: I'm testing in all browsers.  That is to say: FF, IE, Safari, Chrome, and Opera.  It's weird - in FF the "links" menu item is blue, but in the rest they're all blue except for "home".

Comment: A bit off topic, but is anyone else seeing strange code highlighting here? Here's a picture: http://i.imgur.com/mHgcA.png

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too.  What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that  `#access a` is the only `a` child of `#access,` the rest of the links are wrapped in `LI`, and therefore `LI` is the child, not `A`.

`#access ul li:last-child a` points to the last menu item.

Answer (score 1):

All links are the last and only child of their parent (the `li`).

You need to target the last `li` and style its link:

```
#access ul li:last-child a {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're not using `:last-child` properly.

From the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-child-pseudo):

> The `:last-child` pseudo-class represents an element that is the last child of some other element.

When you say:

```
#access a:last-child
```

You're looking for the last child of the element `a` belonging to the `#access` element. But `a` *has* no children, so this won't work properly.

You might want to look for `a`'s parent:

```
#access ul li:last-child a
```

This code looks for the last child of the `ul` and selects it's `a` elements (there is only one).

Comment: You need `#access li:last-child a` instead. `ul:last-child` is looking for the last `ul`, of which there is only one anyway.